# HTML form data to jQuery then back to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML form that I'm using to collect users' input.

After a click on the submit button, I want to display the information provided by the user below the form, but I'm having difficulties manipulating the data using jQuery.

Below is my code:

**HTML:**

```html
<form id="employeeForm">
    <!-- ' action="/" method="get"' Get, not post?? -->
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Employee Data</legend>
        <ul>
            <li class="list"><input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
                <input type="submit" id="addButton-01" value="add" /></li>
            <li class="list"><input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
                <input type="submit" id="addButton-02" value="add" /></li>
            <li class="list"><input type="text" id="idNumber" placeholder="ID Number" />
                <input type="submit" id="addButton-03" value="add" /></li>
            <li class="list"><input type="text" id="jobTitle" placeholder="Job Title" />
                <input type="submit" id="addButton-04" value="add" /></li>
            <li class="list"><input type="text" id="annualSalary" placeholder="Annual Salary" />
                <input type="submit" id="addButton-05" value="add" /></li>
            <li class="list"><textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="addButton-06" value="add" /></li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("jQuery sourced correctly");
// #=ID/single instance-&-dot.=Class/multiple instances
$(function() {
  var newEmployeeButton = $('#newEmployeeButton'); // New Employee button ID
  var employeeEntryForm = $('#employeeForm'); // Form ID
  var textInput = $('input:text'); // all 'input type="text"' areas
  var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
  var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
  var idNumber = $('#idNumber').val();
  var jobTitle = $('#jobTitle').val();
  var annualSalary = $('#annualSalary').val();
newEmployeeButton.show();
employeeEntryForm.hide();
$('#showForm').on('click', function(){
  newEmployeeButton.hide();
  employeeEntryForm.show();
});
employeeEntryForm.on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newText = $textInput.val();
  $('li:last').after('<li>' + newText + '</li>');
  employeeEntryForm.hide();
  newEmployeeButton.show();
  textInput.val('');
});
```

Comment: You said am having trouble getting the data into jquery... can you please share what's exactly that trouble is ?

Comment: Not taking data into JQ

Comment: @nyedidikeke and sono123 Thank you both, I got the code to work.  You each presented a different way to do it which was interesting.  nyedidikeke's method has one submit button which appends to the DOM inside the span tag.  Sono123's method has an individual button for submission of each list item.  Very clever on both, thank you <:  Now to make these submissions additive on the page and total the company monthly expenditures dynamically.  Whew!  Feels like alot for my slow brain!

Comment: @sono123 See above <:

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic implementation of what you're asking. Note the use of the custom attribute "data-label" so you can add the correct labels to the list below the form. Getting the value of a placeholder is not very reliable in my experience, so custom attributes are useful. Also, there is no submit button on this form. That may be a problem with the e.preventDefault() blocking the form submission. This may or may not matter depending on what you are trying to do. Anyway, you can build off of this basic solution. Hope this helps...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <style></style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <form id="employeeForm"> <!-- ' action="/" method="get"' Get, not post?? -->
      <fieldset>
        <legend>New Employee Data</legend>

        <ul>
          <li class="list">
            <input type="text" id="firstName" data-label="First Name" placeholder="First Name" />
            <button id="addButton-01" value="add">Add</button>
          </li>

          <li class="list">
            <input type="text" id="lastName" data-label="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name" />
            <button id="addButton-02" value="add">Add</button>
          </li>

          <li class="list">
            <input type="text" id="idNumber" data-label="ID Number" placeholder="ID Number" />
            <button id="addButton-03" value="add">Add</button>
          </li>

          <li class="list">
            <input type="text" id="jobTitle" data-label="Job Title" placeholder="Job Title" />
            <button id="addButton-04" value="add">Add</button>
          </li>

          <li class="list">
            <input type="text" id="annualSalary" data-label="Annual Salary" placeholder="Annual Salary" />
            <button id="addButton-05" value="add">Add</button>
          </li>

          <li class="list">
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="30" data-label="Comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
            <button id="addButton-06" value="add">Add</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

    <ul id="new-ul">
    </ul>


    <script>    
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").on("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var label = $(this).prev().attr("data-label");
          var value = $(this).prev().val();
          if ( value != "" ) {
            $("#new-ul").append("<li>" + label + " : " + value + "</li>");
          }
        })
      });
    </script>   

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly missing is the `name` attribute on your other input fields; only your `<textarea>` element has it.

Also, you have no variable declared as `$textInput`, but `textInput`, just as no submit `<button>` element.

You may want to append the information provided by the user below the form this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        var employeeEntryForm = $('#employeeForm'),
            displayData = $('#displayData');
        $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            formData = employeeEntryForm.serializeArray();
            // Display user data
            $.each(formData, function(i, data) {
                //console.log(data);
                //console.log(data.name + ": " + data.value);
                displayData.append('<li>' + data.name + ": " + data.value + '</li>');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="employeeForm" name="employeeForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Employee Data</legend>
        <ul>
            <li class="list"><input id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" type="text"> <input id="addButton-01" type="submit" value="add"></li>
            <li class="list"><input id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" type="text"> <input id="addButton-02" type="submit" value="add"></li>
            <li class="list"><input id="idNumber" name="idNumber" placeholder="ID Number" type="text"> <input id="addButton-03" type="submit" value="add"></li>
            <li class="list"><input id="jobTitle" name="jobTitle" placeholder="Job Title" type="text"> <input id="addButton-04" type="submit" value="add"></li>
            <li class="list"><input id="annualSalary" name="annualSalary" placeholder="Annual Salary" type="text"> <input id="addButton-05" type="submit" value="add"></li>
            <li class="list">
            <textarea cols="30" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comments" rows="5"></textarea> <input id="addButton-06" type="submit" value="add"></li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<hr>
<span id="displayData"></span>
```

Comment: See my comment above?  Thank you!  I'm still at it.  Due tomorrow >:

Comment: @PCSailor: please mark my answer as correct as it helped resolve your challenge.

Comment: Hi, I tried but it is giving me this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Hello @PCSailor: from the message you got, I think you mistakenly down voted my answer instead of clicking on the *tick* to accept my answer. Take a close look and click on the tick to accept the answer.